# Ordenar un array de strings tomando en cuenta los valores repetidos que posea - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, ordenamiento

La idea es retornar un **array** de **strings**, ordenado por fecha y por hora. Dichos strings serían como identificadores. Cada valor es tomado de cada uno de esos strings para poder hacer el ordenamiento correspondiente. Yo ahora lo que estoy haciendo es una prueba en la que tengo X cantidad de identificadores desordenados dentro de un arreglo para luego procesarlo.

Ejemplo:

```
const string1 = "mi#20221205#es#164509";
const string2 = "mi#20231205#es#164509";
const string3 = "mi#20210523#es#112034";
const string4 = "mi#20220910#es#124055";
const string5 = "mi#20220415#es#143853";
const string6 = "mi#99999999#es#81211";
const string7 = "mi#99999999#es#81212";
const string8 = "mi#20231206#es#164509";
const string9 = "mi#20231206#es#164510";

const res = [
    string1, 
    string2, 
    string3, 
    string4,
    string5,
    string6,
    string7,
    string8,
    string9,
];
```

Se puede observar que luego del primer **#** hay fechas ficticias (el 99999999 es una exageración por parte mía).
Lo primero que hice para ordernarlos por fecha es lo siguiente:

```
const date = [];

for(let a = 0; a < res.length; a++) {
    const b = res[a].replaceAll('#', ' ').split(' '); // quito el # y devuelvo un arreglo (length 4)
    const e = b.map(f => b.indexOf(f) % 2 !== 0 ? Number(f) : '').filter(Boolean); // me aseguro que los índices que me interesan sean ahora type number y los aparto bajo el criterio indicado
    const g = e.shift(); // aparto las fechas
    date.push(g);
}

date.sort((a, b) => b - a); // las ordeno

const k = [];

date.map(i => {  // compruebo que si existen dentro del arreglo, el valor obtenido sea añadido a un nuevo arreglo
    res.map(j => j.includes(i) ? k.push(j) : false);
});

const l = [... new Set(k)]; // elimino duplicados por efecto del proceso anterior

console.log(l);
```

El resultado obtenido en este punto es:

```
[
  'mi#99999999#es#81211',
  'mi#99999999#es#81212',
  'mi#20231206#es#164509',
  'mi#20231206#es#164510',
  'mi#20231205#es#164509',
  'mi#20221205#es#164509',
  'mi#20220910#es#124055',
  'mi#20220415#es#143853',
  'mi#20210523#es#112034'
]
```

Ahora bien, lo que se me está dificultando es ordenar aquellas fechas que son repetidas en este nuevo arreglo, pero que sus horarios son diferentes. Siendo que me interesa tener en primer lugar las más recientes (con mayor número) y a su vez respetar el arreglo previamente organizado. Esto por más que tenga incontables identificadores y se tenga en cuenta de igual manera para todos los casos. Visto de otra forma:

```
[
  'mi#99999999#es#81212',
  'mi#99999999#es#81211',
  'mi#20231206#es#164510',
  'mi#20231206#es#164509',
  'mi#20231205#es#164509',
  'mi#20221205#es#164509',
  'mi#20220910#es#124055',
  'mi#20220415#es#143853',
  'mi#20210523#es#112034'
]
```

Siendo que los casos ordenados fueron:

```
  'mi#99999999#es#81211',
  'mi#99999999#es#81212',
  'mi#20231206#es#164509',
  'mi#20231206#es#164510',
```

Yo sé que las variables definidas no son las más adecuadas, pero es una prueba rápida y no me centré en ello. Agradezco su aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer tu propio sort basado en ambas propiedades:

```js
const string1 = "mi#20221205#es#164509";
const string2 = "mi#20231205#es#164509";
const string3 = "mi#20210523#es#112034";
const string4 = "mi#20220910#es#124055";
const string5 = "mi#20220415#es#143853";
const string6 = "mi#99999999#es#81211";
const string7 = "mi#99999999#es#81212";
const string8 = "mi#20231206#es#164509";
const string9 = "mi#20231206#es#164510";

const res = [
    string1, 
    string2, 
    string3, 
    string4,
    string5,
    string6,
    string7,
    string8,
    string9,
];

res.sort((a,b) => {
  let [,dateA,, numA] = a.split("#");
  let [,dateB,, numB] = b.split("#");
  //Tratamos todo como numero para mas facilidad
  dateA = Number(dateA);
  dateB = Number(dateB);
  numA = Number(numA);
  numB = Number(numB);
  if(dateA != dateB){
    return dateB-dateA; //Si las fechas son distintas ordenas por la fecha
  } else {
    return numB-numA;  //Si las fechas son iguales ordenas por el numero
  }
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no se necesitan procesos alternos, debería ser suficiente con ordenar el arreglo:

```js
const string1 = "mi#20221205#es#164509";
const string2 = "mi#20231205#es#164509";
const string3 = "mi#20210523#es#112034";
const string4 = "mi#20220910#es#124055";
const string5 = "mi#20220415#es#143853";
const string6 = "mi#99999999#es#81211";
const string7 = "mi#99999999#es#81212";
const string8 = "mi#20231206#es#164509";
const string9 = "mi#20231206#es#164510";

const res = [
    string1, 
    string2, 
    string3, 
    string4,
    string5,
    string6,
    string7,
    string8,
    string9,
];

res.sort((a, b) => b > a); // Ordenar de forma descendente
const l = [... new Set(res)]; // ¿Se necesita esto? ¿Hay duplicados?

console.log(l);
```